# Wordpress - how to change display of element from 3 column to two column

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I am editing a website for a friend and I would like to change some content from a 3 column view to a two column view.

This is the first time I'm using wordpress, and though I'm not sure, I believe that the website uses some sort of plugin to achieve this 3 column presentation.

[image: Here is a screenshot of how it looks right now]

I want to remove the middle column, making the columns on the left and right wider to cover the extra space.

The HTML in the page's editor looks like this:

```
<h3>Camp Schedule</h3>
[third]
<h4>Boy's Camp</h4>
<strong>Ages 11-18
June 5-8, 2012</strong>
Early Registration Fee $110
Late Registration Fee $130
Sinclair Baptist Church
103 Airport Rd
Milledgeville, GA 31061
<a title="Boy’s Camp Ages 11-18" href="/?page_id=333"><strong>Read More</strong></a> [/third]

[third]
<h4>Girl's Camp</h4>
<strong>Ages 11-18
June 12-15, 2012</strong>
Early Registration Fee $110
Late Registration Fee $130
Sinclair Baptist Church
103 Airport Rd
Milledgeville, GA 31061
<a title="Girl’s Camp Ages 11-18" href="/?page_id=335"><strong>Read More</strong></a> [/third]

[third end="true"]
<h4>Kid's Boys &amp; Girl Camp</h4>
<strong>Ages 6-10
June 19-22, 2012</strong>
Early Registration Fee $110
Late Registration Fee $130
Sinclair Baptist Church
103 Airport Rd
Milledgeville, GA 31061
<a title="Kids Camp Ages 6-10" href="/?page_id=337">Read More</a> [/third]
```

I tried messing around a bit, removing one of the [third] tags with it's contents etc, but all I got was the content below the columns to just fill the newly created space.

I could mess around a bit more, but since this is not my website and I'm not exactly familiar with wordpress, I 'd like to not mess everything up.

So, how can I change the content presentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit the theme files. Depending on the structure you will find it directly in the ***index.php*** of the used theme.

The files you are looking for are stored here:
`/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/yourtemplate`

To give you more help, more details on the template/theme and files is needed.

Comment: is there a way to directly access the files via ftp? All I have is access to the website's dashboard

Comment: the current theme should be accessable through the dashboard: Design --> Themes. Depending on the configuration you could edit them under Design --> Editor (admin user). Otherwise you need ftp access to those files.

Comment: Turns out there was a plugin installed and I could use that to add some css, so I just did that, thank you for your help though